# Regex. Excluding matched pattern

Tags: c#, regex

I have a strings

```
name1;name2;name4; vs name3;name4;  
name3;name4; vs name1;name2;name4;
name3;name9; vs name1;name2;name8 vs name5;name4;name7;
name3;name1; vs name1;name2;name4;
name3;name1;name2 vs name1;name2;
name3;name5; vs name1;name2;name4;
```

How to fix regular expression to get first 3 strings using search condition:
`name2` and `name4` should be in different sides from `vs`?

```
((.*name2.*;)|(.*name4.*;)).* vs .*?((.*name2.*;)|(.*name4.*;))
```

in result should be this

```
name1;name2;name4; vs name3;name4;  
name3;name4; vs name1;name2;name4;
name3;name9; vs name1;name2;name8 vs name5;name4;name7;
```

Comment: Can you share an example of the expected result with a test string or two?

Comment: It is hard to know in your question looking at your strings which ones should match and witch ones should not. Could you edit your question and elaborate better which ones should match and which ones should not?

Comment: added in question

Comment: Could [this](https://regex101.com/r/y3MMS9/1) work?

Comment: @JvdV yup, works fine! thank you! post as answer plz, i will commit it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be looking for something like:

```
^.*\b(name2|name4)\b.* vs .*\b(?!\1)(name2|name4)\b.*$
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/y3MMS9/3)

---

- `^.*` - Start string ancor and match anything but newline zero or more times.
- `\b(name2|name4)\b` - Match a word-boundary, 1st Capture group to match one out of two options and another word-boundary.
- `.* vs .*` - Match anything up to and after literal ' vs '.
- `\b(?!\1)` - Word boundary and negative lookahead for what is captured.
- `(name2|name4)\b` - 2nd Capture group to get the other out of two options followed by another word boundary.
- `.*$` - Match anything up to end string ancor.

Answer (score 0):

First, let me ensure I'm understanding your question. If we consider `vs` as the delimiter we have two or more groups/teams/sets of names. You want to match the lines in which name2 and name4 do not share a set? You have some inconsistency in your input example. Is there a solid specification for the format of the strings?

IE

```
name1;name2;name4; vs name3;name4;  *No match, name2 and name4 share set 1*
name3;name4; vs name1;name2;name4;  *No Match, name2 and name4 share set 2
name3;name9; vs name1;name2;name8 vs name5;name4;name7; *Match, name2 and name4 do not share a set
name3;name1; vs name1;name2;name4; *No match, name2 and name4 share set 2
name3;name1;name2 vs name1;name2; *Match? name2 and name4 do not share a set*
```

If my assumptions are correct, and your inputs are correctly inconsistent you could use something like:

```regex
^(?:(?:(?<!\S)(?:(?:name[0-35-9];?)+)(?: vs |(?!\S)))|(?:(?<!\S)(?:(?:name[0-13-9];?)+)(?: vs |(?!\S))))+$
```

We match on repeating groups that exclude either 2 or 4, where each name possibly ends in a semicolon, and is not surrounded by any non-whitespace character.

https://regex101.com/r/fiVP7Q/1 will explain the grouping much better than I may be able to.

Comment: "name" is just an example here can be anything, like "name.*race.*;"

Comment: and i want to find any row, where "name2 vs name4"  or "name4 vs name2"